# Force ContextMenu to use system resources

Tags: wpf, styles, controls, system, contextmenu

I have imported control style in my app.xaml file, as

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
```

but for the ContextMenu control, I would like to use the wpf buildin style, how can I overwrite that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Style` on your `ContextMenu` to null:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="A metro style button" Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163">
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Style="{x:Null}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Item1"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item2"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
            </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If you want to implicity (rather than explicitly) set all the ContextMenus to use the default non-MahApps style then use:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}"/>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Without setting Style to Null.

[image]

With setting Style to Null.

[image]

If you also need to revert the `MenuItem` style to the default style, then use this:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}"/>
    <Style BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}"/>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```